# Why does Snow Leopard report incorrect battery levels for Bluetooth input devices after switching them to Apple rechargeable batteries?

Tags: macos, mac, peripherals, battery

I have a Magic Trackpad, Magic Mouse and the Apple Wireless keyboard. They work fine. Two days ago, doing my part for the environment, I changed all their batteries to Apple rechargeable batteries.

Today I noticed that the battery level meter for all three devices report the wrong battery level. The trackpad reports 93% charge, the keyboard 75% charge and the mouse 65% charge. This can't be right; these are fully charged new batteries. They can't possible drop that much within 48 hours.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? And are there any solutions?

Comment: Did the devices report 100% full batteries when you put them in? Do you have another device that could check battery levels?

Comment: The original non-rechargeable batteries on the three devices were at 99% to 100% when they were swapped with the rechargeable ones.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of battery are they? And did you charge them, or do you just assume they're charged when you buy them? This is why I ask:

> NiMH and NiCd batteries self discharge at a MUCH faster rate than alkaline batteries.  In fact, at "room temperature" (about 70 degrees F) NiMH and NiCD batteries will self discharge a few percent PER DAY.  Storing them at lower temperatures will slow their self discharge rate dramatically.

[Source](http://www.greenbatteries.com/batterymyths.html).

Comment: They are NiMH batteries. They are from Apple : http://www.apple.com/battery-charger/ They were charged (by me) for the duration as suggested by Apple before use (i.e. until the LED on the charger turned green).

Comment: Apple's batteries are rebranded Sanyo Eneloops which don't self-discharge quickly.  In a drawer, they'll retain 80% of their charge even after a year.